# In Monopoly Deal, does the rent apply to a whole group or each card individually?

Tags: monopoly-deal

If a property specifies 2, 4 and 7 millions for 1, 2 and 3 properties respectively - do I calculate the rent owed once per property group (ie. 4 millions for 2 properties) or individually for each property (ie. 2x4 millions for 2 properties)?

I would say it's the former but I'm not a 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Once per property group.**

Looking at the [rules](http://files.boardgamegeek.com/file/download/48v5wqmr21/monopolyDeal.pdf?), there are two columns, "No of properties owned in set" and "Rent".  That can't be parsed to allow you to collect twice if you have 2 of a color, sorry!